# Is there any alternative to ssh tunnels? (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

My network does not allow port forwarding so I use ssh + an external server to do so but doing this is really clunky and not ideal. Is there any way that is more user-friendly and easy to manage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some services that could simplify tunnel management for you:

- [Mole](https://davrodpin.github.io/mole) [free, actively developed]
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) [freemium]
- VPN: Wireguard [free] - [Help Me Make a Reverse VPN Box](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/g0l1sn/help_me_make_a_reverse_vpn_box/)
- See if your ISP provides a non-CGNAT WAN IP

Comment: My ISP couldn't give us public ips even if they wanted to, I don't know if there's any name for this but its basically a NAT behind a NAT (my ISP uses the services of another ISP to give us internet services)